# How to create non symmetric table using flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to code a simple application using flutter. This is my first one for training.

And I don't find the solution to create a non symmetric table. I tried with a `Table` widget but not possible to have different row/column from what I saw.

Now I made a simple row/column pattern and it's still not what I'm looking for.

This is my actual code :

```dart
Widget TableScore(){
return Expanded(
  child : Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
  children: [
  // premiere colonne : 465 + tuts
    Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: myBoxDecorationScore(),
              child : Text('Tuts', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
          ],
        ),

        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
            decoration: myBoxDecorationScore(),
              child : Text('Tour 5', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),

    // Deuxieme Colonne 3 darts + score total tour
    Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: myBoxDecorationScore(),
              child : Text('1', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: myBoxDecorationScore(),
              child : Text('2', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: myBoxDecorationScore(),
              child : Text('3', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: myBoxDecorationScore(),
              child : Text('6', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),

    Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: myBoxDecorationScore(),
              child : Text('485', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: myBoxDecorationScore(),
              child : Text('501', textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
    ],
   ),
  );
}
```

What i have with this code :

[image: result]

What I want :

[image: goal]

Comment: You might what to see if the `Flexible` class can help, here is a short video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI7x0mAZiY0

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried with flexible but still have same issue. i put all flex 1, and i have exact same result as before,